# Migrating from PyroCMS 2.1.x to 2.2.x

Tags: pyrocms

Im developing a shopping cart system for PyroCMS, but moving my code to 2.2.1 is causing me a few headaches.

I cant find any links that describe the technical changes or how to migrate my existing code over to it.

Is there a public list of technical changes that I can use as a reference?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

this is the change log, you can take a look at new changes

http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/reference/changelog

Answer (score 0):

[Upgrade guide from 2.1.x to 2.2.0](http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.2/manual/reference/upgrade-guides/upgrade-2-1-to-2-2-0) (note step 8 for addons)

[Upgrade from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1](https://www.pyrocms.com/blog/2013/04/release-of-v2-2-1)

Essentially 2.1 to 2.2 needs some care, 2.2.0 to 2.2.1 should be a straightforward backup and replace of the system directory if you're not using Git (if you *do* have the time/ability to learn/use Git, it's hugely beneficial for keeping track of changes).

…and of course always do PyroCMS upgrades on a dev server because it invariably breaks in a way you're not expecting.